# Update an angular treeview directive when a new object is added to the collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a treeview directive credit to http://codepen.io/bachly/pen/KwWrzG  for being my starting block. that I am trying to update when I add objects to the collection. I can update the object and insert the new objects but the treeview directive is never called once the `$scoped` item is updated. 
Ultimately the data used will come from a service at this point I am just testing with mock data.

The original collection looks like this

```
$scope.myList = {
            children: [
              {
                  name: "Event",
                  children: [
                    {
                        name: "Event Date",
                        parent:"Event",
                        children: [
                          {
                              name: "2008",
                              filterType: '_eventStartDate',
                              parent: 'Event'
                          },
                          {
                              name: "2009",
                              filterType: '_eventStartDate',
                              parent: 'Event'
                          }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Event Attendee",
                        parent: "Event",
                        children: [
                          {
                              name: "Person 1",
                              filterType: '_eventAttenddeeName',
                              parent: 'Event Attendee'
                          },
                          {
                              name: "Person 2",
                              filterType: '_eventAttenddeeName',
                              parent: 'Event Attendee'
                          }
                        ]
                    }
                  ]
              }]
   };


   var TheOtherCollection = {
       children: [
         {
             name: "A New Event",
             children: [
               {
                   name: "The Other Date",
                   parent: " A New Event",
                   children: [
                     {
                         name: "2010",
                         FilterType: '_eventStartDate',
                         Parent: '_event'
                     },
                     {
                         name: "2011",
                         FilterType: '_eventStartDate',
                         Parent: '_event'
                     }
                   ]
               }
             ]
         }]
   };
```

This generates a tree view with checkboxes using the following directive and html

```
app.directive('tree', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', 
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            t: '=src',
            filter: '&'
        },
        controller: 'treeController',
        template: '<ul><branch ng-repeat="c in t.children track by $index"  src="c" filter="doSomething(object, isSelected)"></branch></ul>'
    };
});

app.directive('branch', function($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E', 
        replace: true, 
        scope: {
            b: '=src',
            filter: '&',
            checked: '=ngModel'
        },

            template: '<li><input type="checkbox" ng-click="innerCall()" ng-model="b.$$hashKey" ng-change="stateChanged(b.$$hashKey)" ng-hide="visible" /><a>{{ b.name }}</a></li>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

               var clicked = '';
               var hasChildren = angular.isArray(scope.b.children);
                scope.visible = hasChildren;
                if (hasChildren) {
                    element.append('<tree src="b"></tree>');
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
                element.on('click', function(event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    if (hasChildren) {
                        element.toggleClass('collapsed');
                    }
                });
                scope.stateChanged = function(b) {
                    clicked = b;
                };

                scope.innerCall = function() {
                    scope.filter({ object: scope.b, isSelected: clicked });
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

And then the html

```
  <div ng-controller="treeController">
        <tree src="myList" iobj="object" filter="doSomething(object, isSelected)"></tree>

        <a ng-click="clicked()"> link</a>
    </div>
```

When a checkbox is clicked the new collection is added to the existing one using lodashjs

ng-click event

```
$scope.doSomething = function (object, isSelected) {
    if (isSelected) {
        var item = object;
        console.log(item);
        nestAssociation(object, $scope.myList, TheOtherCollection);
    }
}
```

which creates the new array and adds it within the children array

```
function nestAssociation(node, oldCollection, newAggregates) {
    // var item = fn(oldCollection, node.parent);
    var updatedArray = _.concat(oldCollection.children, newAggregates);
    console.log(updatedArray);
    if (updatedArray != null)
        updateMyList(updatedArray);
}
```

I can see in the output I have a new object but I can't get the treeview to update. I have tried within the directive to add a $compile(element) on the click event in the directive but since the array is not built yet nothing changes.

Do I need to add a $watch to this directive and if so where or is there some other way I can get the directive to re-render and display the new nested collection?

**Update**

Base on some of the feedback and questions here is a little more detail around the question. The issue I am seeing is not in the directive as far as moving data around the issue is I cannot get the treeview to re-render once an array is added to the existing model. 
The following link [is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nA8bWBhLR0cYwLXql8ww?p=preview) that shows the project as it currently works. 
Running chrome dev tools I can see in the output the model is updated after a checkbox is selected
[image]

While I see the object is updated, the directive never updates to show the new array added to the object. This is the part that I need help understanding.

thanks in advance

Comment: It would be great if you could create a plunkr or codepen where we could see the actual problem and work in your code (as I understand, the linked codepen was just your starting point).

Comment: Can you post the code of your `updateMyList` function which is called by `nestAssociation()`. I guess this is where you actually save the updated Array in `$scope.myList`

Comment: I have updated my question with a plunker link

Comment: @rlcrews I added more information and added a new plunker

Comment: I think the latest plunker is working, see the Clicked event. please let us know if it is not working  as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the function to the inner directives (which is the best practice), but you have access to `scope.filter`. Not `doSomethingFunction`. This one is `undefined` there.

`filter="doSomething(object, isSelected)"`
 =>
`filter="filter(object, isSelected)"`

```
app.directive('tree', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', 
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            t: '=src',
            filter: '&'
        },
        controller: 'treeController',
        template: '<ul>  
                    <branch ng-repeat="c in t.children track by $index"       
                   src="c" filter="filter(object, isSelected)">  
                    </branch>  
                  </ul>'
    };
});
```

Next :

You can never access `$$` variables in angularJS, because they are private. Maybe you should make one from your DB..., but the `$$hashkey` seems a easy solution though.

`checked` attribute might throw an error, because `ngModel` does not exist on your tree directive template. (put at least a `?` before)

A checkbox can not have as model a $$hashkey.
Ng-change and ng-click will always be called at the same time, use the simplest one.

```
app.directive('branch', function($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E', 
        replace: true, 
        scope: {
            b: '=src',
            filter: '&'
        },

            template: '<li><input type="checkbox" ng-click="innerCall(b.$$hashKey)" ng-model="isChecked" ng-hide="visible" /><a>{{ b.name }}</a></li>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

               scope.isChecked = false;
               var hasChildren = angular.isArray(scope.b.children);
                scope.visible = hasChildren;
                if (hasChildren) {
                    element.append('<tree src="b"></tree>');
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
                element.on('click', function(event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    if (hasChildren) {
                        element.toggleClass('collapsed');
                    }
                });

                scope.innerCall = function(hash) {
                    if(scope.isChecked){
                       scope.filter({ object: scope.b, isSelected: hash });
                    }

                };
            }
        };
    });
```

**UPDATE**

You have the same `treeController` in your `tree` directive and in your `index.html` view.
**This is what causes the view not to update!**

I deleted the one in your directive, otherwise you'll have a controller for each child.
 You saw the good console.log message in your controller, but it was in a controller for ONE directive.
You were not accessing the controller of the `index.html`.

Then I fixed the `filter` function communication between childs :

You forgot to communicate the filter function when you append new `tree`'s  :

`element.append('<tree src="b" filter="filter({ object: object, isSelected: isSelected })"></tree>');`

Also, in your parent directive template, you also need the hash to send parameters to the function  :
`filter="filter({ object: object, isSelected: isSelected })"`

I edited your Plunker [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/ybPqvuH8ZclyUXls3vIh?p=info) without changing the code with the above comments I made.
(I'm not sure what you write is not what you want and because you did not comment I rather not change it so you still undertand your code fast)
But the view is updating now!
I think a little debug with what you want and the comments above should be enough.

**EDIT 2**
You forgot to return an object with the property `chrilden`. You returned an array, which caused the problem.

```
function updateMyList(data) {
      var transformed = { children : data };
        $scope.myList = transformed;
    }
```

Here is a working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ybPqvuH8ZclyUXls3vIh?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Try $scope.$apply() after adding

Comment: Tried that early on $scope.$apply() or $scope.$apply(function(){...}) will not work as the function is currently in an $apply() cycle. So it can't invoke a new one

Comment: @ricrews You can avoid the $apply cycle problem by wrapping your call to $scope.$apply in a $timeout call